# Doctrine Collection contains empty model object

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I am using Doctrine 1.2 with Zend Framework. When I fetch a result set as a Doctrine collection, the collection object contains an empty model object of a given type if the returned result-set returned from the DB is empty.

This is quite confusing as we are relying on the count method of Doctrine_Collection to show either a listing of the returned results or an appropriate message when the query returns an empty collection.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I also thought this was annoying. You want to test for actual results by calling `Doctrine_Collection::count()`, such as this scenario that we had:

```
if ( $collection->count() ) {
  // display some widget of the members of Doctrine_Collection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method suggested by yitznewton works for me.

Alternatively, you can test a known field for the first element (0) in the collection.

```
if ($collection[0]->id) {}
```